# Rails: DRY in views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, dry

Hy,

I have a layout in the views/layout that has 2 cols and then in every view i have content_for :main_col and content_for :side_col. The problem is that i have more than 5 views with the same content in the content_for :side_col

You have a better idea on how to do this?thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put it into a partial and render the partial where you need it.

**app/views/shared/_sidebar.html.erb**

```
<% content_for :sidebar do %>
  Hello, I am your neighbourhood friendly sidebar!
<% end %>
```

**app/views/somewhere/else.html.erb**

```
<%= render :partial => "shared/sidebar" %>
```

Comment: Yes, thats a great idea!
using the content_for in the partial
thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If you need pass variables to your partials (what I guess you do), use a helper it's a very neat way to DRY your code:

```
# app/views/shared/_side_col.html.erb
<% content_for :side_col do %>
  <ul>
    <% menu_items.each do |item| %>
      <li><%= item %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>

# app/helpers/application_helper.rb
def side_col(menu_items)
  render 'shared/_side_col', :menu_items => menu_items
end

# app/views/your/view.html.erb
<%= side_col your_menu_items_for_this_view %>
```

Comment: thanks but now I my pages are entirely generated by javascript